# How to set up BeagleBone Black to stay off

Tags: beagleboneblack

Please, I have a question about BeagleBone Black. Is there a way how to configure BBB to stay off when power is connected? There is the power button for soft power off. It can be used to power on after BBB is turned off. But BBB always start immidietly when the power is connected. I need it to stay off and wait for the button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using some hardware modification of Beagle-bone board.

At SYS_RESETN pin Reset Min Push Botton must be replaced with Toggle Switch. 
When switch is on state the SYS_RESETIN connected to GND(0 V). The device will not stated till SYS_RESETIN pin is connected to GND(0 V).
When switch is off the SYS_RESETIN will be coneected to VCC(3.3 V)
Now, the device will operate normally.

The schematic can be found [here](https://github.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/blob/master/BBB_SCH.pdf).

Hope, This will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am not sure, if I understand Your solution, but what if I want to power the BBB off? If I use reset pin with toggle switch, it won't halt OS correctly and system partition can be damaged, doesn't it?